# Why does [ContractAnnotation] not work in a nullable context?

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I have currently the following situation which is working perfectly using vanilla `Jetbrains.Annotations` and with disabled nullable annotations.

```
#nullable disable
[ContractAnnotation("parameter:null => notnull")]
[CanBeNull]
string Check([CanBeNull] string parameter)
{
  return parameter == null ? "ParameterIsNull" : null;
}

void Foo([CanBeNull] string value)
{
  if (Check(value) is null) {
    // no warning -> CORRECT
    var length = value.Length;
  }
  else {
    // WARNING: Possible NullableReferenceException -> CORRECT
    var length2 = value.Length;
  }
}
```

But when I activate the nullable annotations, my IDE suggests me to use type annotations.
As a result, a possible `NullableReferenceException` warning is shown, which is simply invalid.

```cs
#nullable enable
[ContractAnnotation("parameter:null => notnull")]
string? Check(string? parameter)
{
  return parameter == null ? "ParameterIsNull" : null;
}
void Foo(string? value)
{
  if (Check(value) is null) {
    // WARNING: Possible NullableReferenceException -> WRONG!!!
    var length = value.Length;
  }
  else {
    // WARNING: Possible NullableReferenceException -> CORRECT
    var length2 = value.Length;
  }
}
```

I've tried to find some appropriate annotations, but only found the following:

- `AllowNull`
- `DisallowNull`
- `MaybeNull`
- `NotNull`
- `MaybeNullWhen`
- `NotNullWhen`
- `NotNullIfNotNull`
- `MemberNotNull`
- `MemberNotNullWhen`
- `DoesNotReturn`
- `DoesNotReturnIf`

I would require a `[NotNullIfNull]` on the "parameter" or similar?